# MongoDB lookup gives correct output but doesn't update collection

Tags: mongodb, lookup, mongo-shell

I have the following collections:

phones:

```
{"_id": {
    "$oid": "61d376c0b9887d4e736e6acb"
},
"brand": "Nokia",
"name": "Nokia 3210",
"picture": "https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/no3210b.gif",
"phoneId": "1" }
```

reviews:

```
{"_id": {
    "$oid": "61d333d0ac2d25f88d0bc8fa"
},
"phoneId": "1",
"rating": "3",
"dateOfReview": {
    "$date": "2008-11-18T00:00:00.000Z"
},
"title": "Ok phone to tide me over",
"userId": "47599" }
```

I'm running the following aggregation both on MongoCompass and MongoShell and gives me the expected result:

```
db.phones.aggregate([{$lookup: {
 from: 'reviews',
 localField: 'phoneId',
 foreignField: 'phoneId',
 as: 'reviews'
}}])

{ _id: ObjectId("61d376c0b9887d4e736e6acb"),
  brand: 'Nokia',
  name: 'Nokia 3210',
  picture: 'https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/no3210b.gif',
  phoneId: '1',
  reviews: 
   [ { _id: ObjectId("61d333d0ac2d25f88d0bc8fa"),
       phoneId: '1',
       rating: '3',
       dateOfReview: 2008-11-18T00:00:00.000Z,
       title: 'Ok phone to tide me over',
       userId: '47599' } ] }
```

But when I check the collection there is no field reviews, how can I do to add it to the collection permanently? Since I have a lot of reviews for each phone I would also like to add to the reviews' array in phones only the 20 most recent ones that match the phoneId, is it possible?

Comment: Especially if you want only the 20 most recent, why get into the hassle of managing a "rolling" list in the `phones` document that dupes data in the `reviews` collection?  Do the `lookup` as you are doing now.

Comment: I'm writing a Java application that shows the specs of the phone and below its reviews (I have 10k phones and 67k reviews). Since they are showed togheter I would like to embed the 20 most recent so they are available with a single read operation, without accessing the other collection every time. I followed the subset pattern for one to many relationships showed here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for each phone # reviews is >> 20, you might wish to consider going after the reviews *first*, then doing a `$lookup` into phones.  For a single known phone lookup the following will work; it will *not* work for >1 phone because the `$limit` cannot reference data fields (i.e. `phoneId`)

```
db.Xreviews.aggregate([
    {$match: {"phoneId":"2"}}
    ,{$sort: {"dateOfReview":-1}} // no getting around the desc sort..
    ,{$limit: 20}  // but we now limit to ONLY 20 reviews.

    // Put them "back together" as an array called "reviews"
    ,{$group: {_id:"$phoneId", reviews: {$push: "$$CURRENT"}}}

    // ... and pull in the phone data:
    ,{$lookup: {from: "Xphones", localField: "_id", foreignField: "phoneId", as: "X" }}
]);
```

The following will work across 1 or more `phone` or all of them BUT the consideration is the reviews array could be very large before being passed to the `$slice` operator to cut it back to 20:

```
db.Xreviews.aggregate([
    // $match for anything or nothing here; then:
    {$sort: {"dateOfReview":-1}}

    //  The order of the _id is not deterministic BUT the docs will be
    //  pushed onto the reviews array correctly in desc order:
    ,{$group: {_id:"$phoneId", reviews: {$push: "$$CURRENT"}}}

    //  Now simply overwrite the reviews array a shortened version:
    ,{$addFields: {reviews: {$slice: ["$reviews",20] }}}

 
    ,{$lookup: {from: "Xphones", localField: "_id", foreignField: "phoneId", as: "X" }}
]);
```

These two solutions end up with the phone details being stored in field 'X' which is an array of 1 item.  Since we know the phoneID is 1:1, if we wish to get fancy, we can add this after the `$lookup`:

```
   // Pull item[0] out and merge with reviews AND make that the new
   // document:
   ,{$replaceRoot: { newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [ "$$CURRENT", {$arrayElemAt:["$X",0]} ]} }}
    ,{$unset: "X"}   // drop X completely
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second solution and the first steps work very well to get the top 20 most recent reviews for each phone, but unlike the reviews field, the X field that I get after the lookup is empty.

Comment: @SalvatoreLombardi That means the `phoneId->phoneId` lookup is mismatching.   I know the logic works because I reproduced whole data env on my side.   Did you change my `Xphones` back to your `phones`?   If yes, then I suspect your `phoneId` is a string in one collection and an integer in the other.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong, maybe the name of the localField, the Ids are both strings. Anyway I used the command in the answer that I added and seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) and [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) pipeline stages to write data back to your database.

Note that these stages have to be the last stage in your pipeline.

E.g.

```js
db.phones.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'reviews',
      localField: 'phoneId',
      foreignField: 'phoneId',
      as: 'reviews'
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: 'phones', // collection-name
      on: 'phoneId',  // the identifier, used to identify the document to merge into
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to add the result of the lookup to the target collection and make it persistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem combining the two solutions proposed by Buzz and MarcRo:

```
    db.reviews.aggregate([
{
    $sort: {
        "dateOfReview":-1
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$phoneId',
        reviews: {
            $push: '$$CURRENT'
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        reviews: {
            $slice: [
                '$reviews',
                20
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $merge: {
        into: 'phones',
        on: '_id'
    }
}])
```